# P&T Contact Form Plugin: HTML Email Templates

Tags: plugins, emails

Can you create HTML templates using Twig/Craft tags to style the body of the email message sent by the P&T contact form plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to build a template for all the e-mail messages, including the ones sent by P&T Contact Form Plugin, then you should at least have Craft Client edition, which supports *Custom HTML email templates*.

If you have Client or Pro, you can set an e-mail template in your Email Settings (in the field called HTML Email template).

---

If, on the other hand, you want to change the text sent by the plugin (so the body of your e-mail), I don't think there's a way to do that without altering the plugins code.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your answer. Yes it was the second part of your answer I was referring to. I'd like to be able to style the body of the email message sent by the P&T contact form.