# Include additional fields in Craft form notification template

Tags: templating, emails, plugin-contactform

I'm using the Craft Contact Form template.  I need to include some additional content in the notification email.  I can't for the life of me find how to do this.

I've seen this:
[P&T Contact Form Plugin: HTML Email Templates](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2232/pt-contact-form-plugin-html-email-templates?rq=1)

But not sure how to apply the additional fields.  Here is my contact form template (markup removed for ease of reading).

```
{# form markup #}
    <select class='form__input' name="message[About]">
        {% nav link in craft.entries.section('products') %}
            <option value="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</option>
        {% endnav %}
        <option value="Services">Services</option>
        <option value="Consultancy">Consultancy</option>
        <option value="General enquiry">General enquiry</option>
    </select>
    <div class='input'>
        <label class='form__label' for='fromEmail'>Your email address</label>
        <input class='form__input' id='fromEmail' name='fromEmail' type='email' placeholder='Email address' value='{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromEmail }}{% endif %}'>
    </div>
    <div class='input'>
        <label class='form__label' for='message'>Details</label>
        <textarea class='form__input form__input--textarea' id='message' name='message' placeholder='Tell us more'>{% if message is defined %}{{ message.message }}{% endif %}</textarea>
    </div>
{# form closing markup/submit button #}
```

any help, phenomenally appreciated!

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the GitHub page for the ContactForm plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm) under the section for adding additional fields, you'll see that you need to change the name of the `message` field to `message[body]`. Try that to see if it helps. I would imagine leaving it as `message` means that it overwrites the values of the other additional fields.

Comment: Super... thanks for pointing me in the right direction.