# Choose custom email template for Contact Form plugin

Tags: templating, plugin-contactform

I could've sworn I've read somewhere on here that the contact form plugin should use the same template as defined in the site's email settings, but it's not working for me.

Does anyone know if the Contact Form plugin supports this (and has it working)?

Comment: Here's where I saw it: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2232/pt-contact-form-plugin-html-email-templates

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the [answer in the post you linked to](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2232/pt-contact-form-plugin-html-email-templates) is wrong in the context of the Contact Form plugin.

Craft only takes the custom "HTML Template Path" email setting into account when [EmailService's](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EmailService) [sendEmailByKey](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EmailService#sendEmailByKey-detail) is called, which is used for pre-defined Craft emails.

The Contact Form uses [EmailService's](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EmailService) [sendEmail](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EmailService#sendEmail-detail), which won't take it into account.

It hasn't been released as part of an official Contact Form plugin release yet so there's no documentation, but thanks to [this pull request](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm/commit/167e830665683deab22026ea3808d00f4b33e107), you've got an `onBeforeMessageCompile` event that will give a plugin a chance to modify the contents of the email.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the confusion. Easiest thing was just adding the template HTML to the email body within ContactFormService.php.

Answer (score 1):

As Brad points out in his answer, the Contact Form plugin doesn't use the same template. I found the easiest thing to do was replace:

```
$email->body      = $message->message;
```

with:

```
$htmlTemplateTopHalf= <<<TEMPLATETOP
    // insert html here
TEMPLATETOP;

$htmlTemplateBottomHalf= <<<TEMPLATEBOTTOM
    // insert html here
TEMPLATEBOTTOM;

$email->body      = $htmlTemplateTopHalf;
$email->body      .= $message->message;
$email->body      .= $htmlTemplateBottomHalf;
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, you can use [Contact Form Templates](https://github.com/lukeyouell/craft-contactformtemplates) to make custom email templates in Craft CMS 3.